# How does Costco avoid having to use Apple In App Purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase

I'm developing a membership based app and site for information sharing. I know that Apple has in-app purchase and it provides an easy way for developers to accept payment for digital goods subscriptions. However, I know that Apple wants a cut of every subscription especially if the purchase is something that isn't "real world".

How does a company like CostCo offer membership purchases within their app but do not need to abide by the Apple In App Purchase requirement?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your service. For a list of apps that may use purchase methods other than in-app purchase see paragraph [3.1.3 Other Purchase Methods](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#other-purchase-methods) in the App Store Review Guidelines.